# Object is invisible, even though its unhidden

Tags: objects

Everytime i create an object its invisible no matter what the object is, also im new to blender so sorry if this is stupid [image]

Comment: Hello it looks like you've created a mesh > Circle, and it is visible, we can see the circle

Comment: If you've just added that Circle object, it seems to be visible to me! What happens if you add a solid object such as a Cube of Cylinder? - The Circle is just a ring of Vertices connected by Edges so won't show up very well when it's not selected.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.